# JQuery: Check if any dropdown on the page currently has a particular value selected?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, innerhtml, dynamic-forms

What I am trying to achieve is to check all dropdowns on the page to see if any currently have the value `tags` selected.

To cut down on the checking, only the dropdowns with the class `tag` should only need to be checked.

I have the following code and have tried many different things but I still can't figure it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ubTe/44/

It's driving me insane so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo showing the basic technique: http://jsfiddle.net/AxTjV/

```
$('select.className[value=searchValue]')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps a lot but I still can't get it to work with my code :'( 

http://jsfiddle.net/5ubTe/48/ Not sure what's wrong with it!!!

Comment: Silly typo, got your code to work with what I had but still having issues with the dropdowns inbetween the first and last rows. e.g. if there is a dropdown with `tags` selected in the middle but the last row is set to anything else, the button will enable. Like wise if you delete the additional rows until you arrive at one with `tags` the button remains enabled.... http://jsfiddle.net/5ubTe/58/